# Retrieve Activities/History Data Using SugarCRM 6.5 REST API

Tags: api, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I would like to get Activities and History Subpanel data for Opportunity records using **SugarCRM 6.5.x REST API v4_1**. Can anyone help?